# Debug generated Query without manual declaring variables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I use this on my context to show a generated SQL Query:

```
context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Then the SQL Query is printed with these variable information for example:

```
-- p__linq__0: '2016' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: '12' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__2: '05.12.2016 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)
```

I simple want to execute the complete Query from the Management Studio, to analyze the Queryplan.

It's hard to make correct `DECLARE` statements from the comments every time I want to debug something.

Is there some easier way to show the queryplan, without manualy declare the variables?